# Hibernate: Use HQL inside @Formula annotation?

Tags: hibernate, annotations, hql, formula

From what I've been testing it seems that you can only use standard SQL inside a @Formula annotation. The documentation is not very descriptive about this feature (I've found one paragraph about it at most), so I was wondering whether HQL can be used somehow or whether there's another feature that would let me load an object's property with a HQL query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right . `@Formula` only allows to use the actual column name .

The important characteristic of HQL is use the java property name to refer the actual column name . If you want to refer the property names when deriving your formula value  , you can simply implement the logic of the formula in the getter of your mapped POJOs.